# Model usage when constructing grid

Tags: iggrid

What is the model using for when constructing grid?  I have created two grids with different model but same code excepted model.  It works same.

```
@Html.Infragistics().Grid<Model1>



@Html.Infragistics().Grid<Model2>
```

Thanks

Wilson

Comment: What is the issue that you're experiencing?

Comment: I want to know what is the meaning of ".Grid<T>"?  It works seem even Type is difference.